# Index out of range error in Python (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexoutofrangeexception

I can't seem to find the issue here that I am getting out of range issue:

```
layerZ = [layer_1,layer_2,layer_3,layer_4,layer_5,layer_6,layer_7,layer_8,layer_9,layer_10,layer_11,layer_12,layer_13]
    for x in range(0, 12):
        layerZ_total = [np.size(layerZ[x])]
        layerZ_sp = [np.count_nonzero(layerZ[x]==0)]
        layerZ_nonSp = [np.count_nonzero(layerZ[x])]

        #Printing the results on scree to trace
        print "Layer:",x+1,"Threshhold:",repr(ths),"Total Parameters: ",layerZ_totParam[x],"# Sp: ",layerZ_sp[x],"# Remained : ",layerZ_nonSp[x],"Sp %: ",float(layerZ_sp[x])/layerZ_total[x]
```

Comment: Your `layerZ_total`, `lazerZ_sp` and `layerZ_nonSp` lists all have length 1, because you create them from scratch each iteration. They therefor can't have any other indices than `0`, but you used `x` to index them.

Comment: Ahh, thanks @MartijnPieters. I should use `layerZ_total[x]=...` for all of them then. right?

Comment: I have no idea what your code is supposed to do. All I can do is point out the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
layerZ = [layer_1,layer_2,layer_3,layer_4,layer_5,layer_6,layer_7,layer_8,layer_9,layer_10,layer_11,layer_12,layer_13]

layerZ_total = []
layerZ_sp = []
layerZ_nonSp = []


for x in range(0, 12):
    layerZ_total.append(np.size(layerZ[x]))
    layerZ_sp.append(np.count_nonzero(layerZ[x]==0))
    layerZ_nonSp.append(np.count_nonzero(layerZ[x]))

    #Printing the results on scree to trace
    print "Layer:",x+1,"Threshhold:",repr(ths),"Total Parameters: ",layerZ_total[x],"# Sp: ",layerZ_sp[x],"# Remained : ",layerZ_nonSp[x],"Sp %: ",float(layerZ_sp[x])/layerZ_total[x]
```

In your code, the lists `layerZ_total`, `layerZ_sp` and `layerZ_nonSp` were reinitialized with a single value everytime inside the loop, therefore containing only one element at `index 0` inside them, when you tried accessing some `x index`, the `list index out of range` error popped up.

And if you were to do processing on every `layer_*` of `layerZ` list(depending on your requirements), you need to `range(0, 13)` as after doing this `x` will take on the values `0` to `12` thereby processing every `layer` in your `layerZ` list